# D3 transition: duration doesn't work for line path

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, transition

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to animate my graph with a line that would take 1s to appear (using `.transition().duration(1000)`).

Unfortunately, I can't get this result. The `.duration(1000)` seems not to work for the line draw.

Abstract of my

```
svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline(xy));
```

If i put a `.transition().duration(1000).style("color", "red)`, the font becomes red in 1s.

My question: why does the duration work for the color but not the line draw?

If you could help me, I would be very very grateful!

---

I you need my whole code, I but it there:

```
//VOLCAN FUNCTION
function draw_volcan(url){
    d3.select("svg").remove() // remove the old graph

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    d3.json(url, function(error, data) { //chargement des data volcans
        if(error) throw ('There was an error while getting geoData: '+error);
        //get in an array the occurance of eruptions
        var volcans_incidence_annee_2018 = new Array(59).fill(0) // on prépare une array avec pour le nombre d'éruptions de volcan par année
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            var single_date_index = d.Date-1960     //année-1960 = index où il faudra ajouter 1 pour l'occurence de l'année
            volcans_incidence_annee_2018[single_date_index] += 1 //ajoute 1 d'occurance à l'année souhaitée
            });
        var volcans_incidence_annee = new Array(56).fill(0)

        for(i in volcans_incidence_annee_2018){ //créé un array volcans_incidence_annee qui contient les données de 1960 à 2015 uniquement
            if(i<56){
                volcans_incidence_annee[i] = volcans_incidence_annee_2018[i]
            };
        };

        var year_array = []
        for(var i = 1960; i<=2015; i++) {year_array.push(i);} //créé un array avec chaque année

        //create array with all the points
        var xy=[];
        for(var i = 0; i < year_array.length; i++ ) {
            xy.push({x: year_array[i], y: volcans_incidence_annee[i]});
        };

        // set the ranges
        var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1960, 2015]).range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([Math.min(...volcans_incidence_annee), Math.max(...volcans_incidence_annee)]).range([height, 0]);

        // create a line function that can convert data[] into x and y points
        var valueline = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.x);})
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.y);});


        // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
        // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
        // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
        var svg = d3.select("#graph_draw").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // Add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline(xy));

        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
        //svg.append("g").attr("d", line(+volcans_incidence_annee));
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

In D3, a transition changes a DOM element from an initial state, the *source*  state, to a final state, the *target* state.

Everything before creating a transition with `selection.transition` belongs to the initial state, and everything after it belongs to the desired (target) state.

That said, the issue in your question is quite simple: you cannot interpolate the creation of a class or the definition of the `d` attribute. As Bostock (D3 creator) [once said](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/):

> When modifying the DOM, use selections for any changes that cannot be interpolated; only use transitions for animation. For example, it is impossible to interpolate the creation of an element: it either exists or it doesn’t.

We can clearly see this in the demos below.

It makes no sense transitioning from having no `d` attribute to having one:

```js
var d = "M38.8 68.4l37.8 7.9 1.6-7.6-37.8-7.9-1.6 7.6zm5-18l35 16.3 3.2-7-35-16.4-3.2 7.1zm9.7-17.2l29.7 24.7 4.9-5.9-29.7-24.7-4.9 5.9zm19.2-18.3l-6.2 4.6 23 31 6.2-4.6-23-31zM38 86h38.6v-7.7H38V86z";

var d2 = "M84.4 93.8V70.6h7.7v30.9H22.6V70.6h7.7v23.2z";

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var path = svg.append("path")
  .style("fill", "#f48023")
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("d", d)

var path2 = svg.append("path")
  .style("fill", "#bcbbbb")
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("d", d2)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

However, we can transition from `0` opacity to `1`:

```js
var d = "M38.8 68.4l37.8 7.9 1.6-7.6-37.8-7.9-1.6 7.6zm5-18l35 16.3 3.2-7-35-16.4-3.2 7.1zm9.7-17.2l29.7 24.7 4.9-5.9-29.7-24.7-4.9 5.9zm19.2-18.3l-6.2 4.6 23 31 6.2-4.6-23-31zM38 86h38.6v-7.7H38V86z";

var d2 = "M84.4 93.8V70.6h7.7v30.9H22.6V70.6h7.7v23.2z";

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var path = svg.append("path")
  .style("fill", "#f48023")
  .attr("d", d)
  .style("opacity", 0)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .style("opacity", 1);
  

var path2 = svg.append("path")
  .style("fill", "#bcbbbb")
  .attr("d", d2)
  .style("opacity", 0)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .style("opacity", 1);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer!
Wouldn't it be possible to create a `d` attribute that has `.style("opacity", 0)`and that doesn't follow any particular path, and then make a `.transition()` to the read `d` attribute with full opacity and the correct path?

Comment: The d attribute is a string, therefore the transition uses a string interpolation. What would be the interpolation from nothing to the complete d attribute? Again, this **doesn't** work.